# How do I increase the upload size in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, ftp, uploading, image-size

My blog runs on the comicPress theme powered by Wordpress, on Altervista hosting service. I purchased the second level domain and therefore I aim customizing everything I need to.

I normally upload images through the menu `Comics -> add comic -> upload media` and then upload from my pc.

I want to change the size of images I upload there. So far I've been trying the following methods:

1)

I copy/pasted the script below in `functions.php` file and uploaded it but it didn't work:

```
@ini_set( 'upload_max_size' , '25M' );
@ini_set( 'post_max_size', '25M');
@ini_set( 'max_execution_time', '300' );
```

2)

then I tryed to configure a ftp server after having installed Filezilla. For I read, it is a requirement for accessing the root of my website and exploting a php.ini file (which will be create and saved there) which allows modifying the size for uploading. But while opening FileZilla server I got this error:

```
     FileZilla Server 0.9.58 beta
    Copyright 2001-2016 by Tim Kosse (tim.kosse@filezilla-project.org)
    https://filezilla-project.org/
    Connecting to server localhost:14147...
    Connected, waiting for authentication
    Logged on
    You appear to be behind a NAT router. Please configure the passive mode settings and forward a range of ports in your router.
    Warning: FTP over TLS is not enabled, users cannot securely log in.
```

So what should I do for being able to upload bigger images?

Answer (score 1):

Josip has given a great explanation. Here's other way you can do it. Locate `wp-config.php` file in your file manager.

There you can search using (Command + F), for this function:

```
define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT','32M');
```

you can simply change it to `64M`.

```
define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT','64M');
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a `.htaccess` also.

You can copy/paste this into your .htaccess file so you can modify your requirements.

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 64M
php_value post_max_size 64M
php_value max_execution_time 300
php_value max_input_time 300
```

if this doesn't help you, /or if you are on shared hosting, you need to contact your hosting provider so they can modify your upload sizes.